# Strings with malloc in C

Tags: c

I am writing a very simple program to copy a string using *malloc*.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

char * copyStr(char s[])
    {
      int len = strlen(s); //find length of s
      char * copy; 
      copy = (char *)malloc(len); //dynamically allocate memory 
      int i; 
      for(i=0;i<len;i++) 
       {
         copy[i]=s[i];  //copy characters               
       }
       return copy; //return address
    }

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
     char * str;
     str = "music is my aeroplane";
     char * res;
     res = copyStr(str);
     printf("The copied string is : %s",res);
     getch();
    }
```

The desired output is:

```
The copied string is : music is my aeroplane
```

The current output is:

```
The copied string is : music is my aeroplaneOMEeJ8«≤╝
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Your copy is not a C string, because it is not null terminated.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @SouravGhosh That's an interesting read, thanks.

Comment: I love casting malloc. The misguided, lenient C type system is no reason to be sloppy. C++ tightened it wherever it could for a reason.

Comment: To clarify what @PeterA.Schneider wrote: Every unnecessary cast inhibits type-checking by the compiler. Which in turn has potential to not detect a type error automatically. Thus the general rule only to use a cast iff 1) it is absolutely necessary, 2) you fully understand **all** implications, and 3) completely accept them. Said than, casting `void *` definitively **is** a bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A C string is null terminated. Add a null character (ie the char which ASCII code is 0) at end of the string :

```
char * copyStr(char s[])
{
  size_t len = strlen(s); //find length of s
  char * copy; 
  copy = (char *)malloc(len + 1); //dynamically allocate memory
                           /* One more char must be allocated for the null char */

  size_t i; 
  for(i=0;i<len;i++) 
   {
     copy[i]=s[i];  //copy characters               
   }
   copy[i] = '\0'; // HERE
   return copy; //return address
}
```

It is better to use `size_t` for the lengths because it is unsigned.

Comment: You could insofar it will compile, but don't. NULL is not a char (1 byte) but a pointer not set : `(void *)0`

Comment: @Arjun: A simple `0` would do as well. And please note that the ASCII character named `NUL` is something completely different then the null-pointer constant `NULL`.

Comment: @Arjun No, it isn't. It would work for complex reasons that we don't need to discuss. But a NULL pointer and a null character are two different beasts that are confusingly named in the C standard.

Comment: @Art Okay, thanks. I think size-wise we prefer '\0' right? 4 bytes vs 1 byte?

Comment: @Art The C standard is very clear about this, the ASCII character's name with value 0 is called `NUL`, the pointer which compares true to 0 is called `NULL`.

Comment: @hroptatyr "Very clear" would be different. I'm glad they don't have _NUL, __NULL, NIL or null.

Comment: @hroptatyr Is it? I can't find the string "NUL " anywhere in the C11, C99 or C89 standards. "null character" is used all over the place though.

Comment: @Art Sorry, my bad, you're right, the official final C11 standard does talk about "null characters" and "null wide characters", probably because ASCII isn't mandatory and `NUL` is an ASCII-specific name; I take everything back I said

Comment: @Art Interestingly NUL appears in the n1570 draft in just one place, a footnote in 7.4.1.2. Afaics it is not defined in stdio.h; I always thought the canonical way to write the null char is `'\0'`.

Comment: I prefer to use '\0' because it's clearer what it's actually supposed to mean. But 0 will always be correct too.

Comment: @Arjun  `'\0'` is an `int`.  `0` is an `int` - Both have the same size.  Both are suitable for _null character_ assignment.  `NULL` is the _null pointer constant_.  It is best used with pointers.  Do not use when assigning the _null character_.

Answer (score 5):

Strings in C are null-terminated.

> The C programming language has a set of functions implementing
>   operations on strings (character strings and byte strings) in its
>   standard library. Various operations, such as copying, concatenation,
>   tokenization and searching are supported. For character strings, the
>   standard library uses the convention that strings are null-terminated:
>   a string of n characters is represented as an array of n + 1 elements,
>   the last of which is a "NUL" character.

In this case, you should have enough memory to store the original string contents and the "NUL" character (length+1). And don't forget to ensure the presence of the "NUL" character after the end of the string.

There are many possible ways to implement `char * copyStr(char[])` function:

1) Your way (corrected):

```
char * copyStr(char s[])
{
    int i;
    size_t len = strlen( s );

    char * p = (char*) malloc( len + 1 );

    for( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        p[i] = s[i];

    p[i] = '\0';

    return p;
}
```

2) Using `memcpy()`:

```
char * copyStr(char s[])
{
    size_t len = strlen( s );

    char * p = (char*) malloc( len + 1 );

    memcpy( p, s, len );

    p[ len ] = '\0';

    return p;
}
```

3) Using `strcpy()`:

```
char * copyStr(char s[])
{
    size_t len = strlen( s );
    char * p = (char*) malloc( len + 1 );
    strcpy( p, s );
    return p;
}
```

4) Using `strdup()`:

```
char * copyStr(char s[])
{
    return strdup(s);
}
```

Note: For every `malloc()` function call you need a `free()` function call, your `main()` needs a little modification for correctness:

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    char * str;
    char * res;

    str = "music is my aeroplane";

    res = copyStr( str );

    printf( "The copied string is : %s", res );

    free(res); /* freedom */

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Brilliant, I'm kind of lost for words. Yes, I understand that I should free the dynamically allocated memory. I forgot previously..

Comment: I see a bright future for you on StackOverflow and the yet unrevealed Documentation ;) keep up the good work soldier ;)